# How to connect child database from master database in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

> Hi
>   I have master database,it contains number of  child databases and no.of tables
>   in each child database. Now i want to update child data base tables. then how to connect >child database in php.
>   please help me.

Code:

**index.php**

```
  <?php
   include 'includes/connection.php';

   $query="SELECT * FROM account_info";

   $result=mysql_query($query);

   while ($user=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<h3>" .$user['account_status'] . "</h3>";
   }

   ?>
```

**connection.php**

```
 <?php

   $dbhost='localhost';
   $dbuser='';
   $dbpassword='';

   $dbname=  'movico_1496_123456';

   $conn=mysql_connect('$dbhost','$dbuser','dbpassword');
   mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("unable to connect to  the database");

   ?>
```

Comment: Variables g.can not be in single quotes or else they will be treating as string.

Comment: If the databases ore on the same server then just specify which table you want to use by including the 'database' name in the table reference. i.e. db1.table1  join db2.table2 on.... Reference is here: [mysql - 5.5/en/select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html). If on different servers then it ain't so easy.